# WiFi functionality in metro-style Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, windows-8

I can not seem to find any information about how to utilize wifi functionality in Windows Store apps (beyond simple stuff like getting info on the network currently connected.)

Specifically, for an app that can run on an ARM tablet, how would one, for example, programmatically connect to a specified SSID, access the scan list, etc.?

The latest I read about this (from this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tailoringappsfordevices/thread/2a51365f-5d51-41ca-b301-4d728e86c516) was from about 6 months ago, prior to the release of the main SDK, and stated that basically, there were NO wlan apis available for metro apps.

Has anything changed regarding this?  It seems unlikely that there would simply be no way of controlling wifi on any windows 8 devices...

Comment: To get your specific question answered you should contact Microsoft.

Comment: This isn't a question that can be answered on Stackoverflow.  You should contact Microsoft instead.

Comment: The current Win RT SDK is public.  Instead of asking this question just reference it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 store apps are not supposed to control wifi, it goes against their sandbox guidelines that applications should not be able to change system settings without user knowing about it.

You can get the information regarding which network you are connected to but that's about it.

There can be malicious apps that will cause problem for user if certain system features are exposed and same goes for apps with bugs.